# For efficient algorithm on "minimization" knapsack problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, optimization, packing

Suppose there are two arrays of positive numbers, $a[\cdot]$ and $b[\cdot]$, and value $B>0$. How to pick a set of indexes $I$, so that

$\sum_{i\in{I}}{b[i]}\geq{B}$

To minimize $\sum_{i\in{I}}{a[i]}$

I know this problem sounds like knapsack problem, but the objective is really to minimise, not maximise. Does this make a difference if I want to seek a polynomial-time, approximate algorithm?

Answer (score 10):

There's a simple reduction from knapsack. Binary search for the solution to your knapsack instance, then solve the "dual knapsack" with that value as your covering constraint $B$. Compare the value given by the "dual knapsack" against your knapsack packing constraint, which gives you the direction to continue the binary search.

I think you can use the same rounding approach as the one for knapsack in order to get a PTAS for this problem. [These notes](http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18434S06/knapsack-katherine.pdf) notes should help you do it.

Comment: I think you mean fptas not just ptas.

Answer (score 3):

I found a related MS thesis.

Title: APPROXIMATION ALGORITHMS FOR MINIMUM KNAPSACK PROBLEM
https://www.uleth.ca/dspace/bitstream/handle/10133/1304/islam,%20mohammed.pdf?sequence=1

You can also find related papers in its references.